# A total preorder on a set $S$ can be expressed as a total order on a partition of $S$

Tags: order-theory

I am trying to understand this statement from my Professor.

> A total preorder on a set $S$ can be expressed as a total order on a partition of $S$

So for example, given $r_1 \lesssim r_2$, $r_2 \lesssim r_1$, $r_2 \lesssim r_3$ and $r_3 \not \lesssim r_2$ is equivalent to $\{ r_1, r_2\} < \{r3 \}$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. A total preorder is not a total order only because different elements can be “equal” under it, i.e. $a\le b$ and $b\le a$ doesn’t imply $a=b$.

To show that a total preorder induces a total order on a partition of $S$, consider the relation

$$r\sim s\Leftrightarrow r\le s \land s\le r\;.$$

This is an equivalence relation – it’s clearly symmetric, and it inherits reflexivity and transitivity from the preorder. It partitions $S$ into equivalence classes of elements that are “equal” under the preorder.

The preorder induces a total order on the equivalence classes of $S$ under this equivalence relation:

$$[r]\preccurlyeq[s]\Leftrightarrow r\le s\;.$$

This is well-defined since it doesn’t depend on the representatives: If $r\le s$, $r\sim t$ and $s\sim u$, then $t\le r\le s\le u$ and thus by transitivity $t\le u$. It’s a total order because it inherits reflexivity, transitivity and totality from the preorder, and it’s antisymmetric: If $[r]\preccurlyeq[s]$ and $[s]\preccurlyeq[r]$, then by the definition of $\preccurlyeq$ we have $r\le s$ and $s\le r$, and then by the definition of $\sim$ we have $r\sim s$ and thus $[r]=[s]$.

I’ll leave the details of the “inheritance” claims as an exercise.

Conversely, every total order $\preccurlyeq$ on a partition of $S$ induces a total preorder $\le$ on $S$, again via

$$
r\le s\Leftrightarrow [r]\preccurlyeq[s]\;.
$$

Reflexivity, transitivity and totality are inherited from $\preccurlyeq$, but antisymmetry is not (since $[r]=[s]$ doesn’t imply $r=s$).

These two transformations are inverses of each other, so the total preorders on $S$ and the total orders on partitions of $S$ are in one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining.  I have a follow-up question. Can this be said for an order that is transitive + total but neither reflexive nor irreflexive (let's call is quasi order)? so "a quasi order on a set S can be expressed as a total order on a partition of S" ... I am worried we can't say the same because we remove the reflexive from it.

Comment: @Node.JS: It depends on what exactly you mean by "can be expressed as". I've expanded my answer to show that the total preorders on $S$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the total orders on partitions of $S$. Of course you can still associate a total order on a partition of $S$ with your "quasi order" (e.g. by adding in the diagonal to turn it into a preorder and taking the corresponding total order on a partition) – but this is no longer a one-to-one correspondence, so in that sense the quasi order doesn't "express" a total order on a partition of $S$.